# Error while trying to upload apk file to Browserstack cloud, using Axios / node-fetch

Tags: axios, fetch, webdriver-io, browserstack

I am trying to upload .apk / .ipa file to browserstack cloud programmatically (instead of running the curl command)

**Option 1: Node-fetch api**

```
const myfetch = require('node-fetch');

const buildToPost = {
   file: '</my path>'
};

const options = {
   method: 'POST',
   body: JSON.stringify(buildToPost)
};

myfetch('https://</myusername>:</mykey>@api.browserstack.com/app-automate/upload', options)
   .then(res => res.json())
   .then(res => console.log(res))
   .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error));​
```

But its giving following error:

> { error:    'Invalid format. Refer to REST API document for valid API
>   format - https://www.browserstack.com/app-automate/rest-api' }

**Option 2: Axios API**

```
    const axios = require('axios');

axios.post('https://</myusername>:</mykey>​@api-cloud.browserstack.com/app-automate/upload', {
      File: '</my path>​'
   })
   .then
   ((response) => {
      console.log(response);
   }).catch((error) => {
      console.log((error));
})​
```

Error: data:

> { error:
>            'Invalid format. Refer to REST API document for valid API format - https://www.browserstack.com/app-automate/rest-api' } } }

Curl command reference:

```
curl -u "</myusername>:</mykey>" -X POST https://api-cloud.browserstack.com/app-automate/upload -F "file=@/path/to/app/file/Application-debug.apk" -F 'data={"custom_id": "MyApp"}'
```

[Browserstack sample link](https://www.browserstack.com/app-automate/rest-api)

Comment: Note: File to be uploaded is present on local disk/folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how to do it with `axios`. The important points are:

- Authentication (using the `user` option)
- Use of the `FormData` module to submit multipart data
- Setting the `maxContentLength` option high enough to allow your file to be uploaded.

Code below.

```
import axios from 'axios';
import fs from 'fs';
import FormData from 'form-data';

const formData = new FormData();

// Open file stream
const newFile = fs.createReadStream(binaryPath);

// Add form field params
formData.append('file', newFile, 'my_filename.apk');
formData.append('custom_id', 'npm_uploaded_apk');

axios({
  url: 'https://api-cloud.browserstack.com/app-automate/upload',
  method: 'post',
  headers: formData.getHeaders(),
  auth: {
    username:'my_browserstack_username',
    password: 'my_browserstack_access_key',
  },
  data: formData,
  maxContentLength: 1073741824,
})
  .then(response => {
    // The object with the 'app_url' parameter is in the 'data' field of the response.
    console.log('POST successful: ', response.data);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log('POST error: ', error);
  });
```

More background on this in [this GitHub thread](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/1006#issuecomment-320165427).